# rename file in php

Tags: php

I want to rename `picture` filename (without extension) to `old.jpg` from this code.

I have `picture` file in parent directory and the path is correctly

```
$old="picture";
$new="old.jpg";
rename($old , $new);
```

or this codes

```
$old="\picture";
$new="\old.jpg";
rename($old , $new);

$old="../picture";
$new="../old.jpg";
rename($old , $new);

$old="../picture";
$new="old.jpg";
rename($old , $new);

$old="./picture";
$new="./old.jpg";
rename($old , $new);

rename("picture", "old.jpg");
```

But I get this error:

```
 Warning: rename(picture,old.jpg) [function.rename]: The system cannot find the file specified. (code: 2) in C:\xampp\htdocs\prj\change.php on line 21
```

Comment: Well your paths are clearly not correct

Comment: If its in the parent directory you would use '../picture'

Comment: @Jack a reverse slash (\\), he is using windows

Comment: @Seth forward slash works fine on Windows, but if you want to be portable you'd say DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A relative path is based on the script that's being executed (`$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']` when run in web server) which is not always the file in which the file operation takes place:

```
// index.php
include('includes/mylib.php');

// mylib.php
rename('picture', 'img506.jpg'); // looks for 'picture' in ../
```

Finding a relative path involves comparing the absolute paths of both the executing script and the file you wish to operate on, e.g.:

```
/var/www/html/index.php
/var/www/images/picture
```

In this example, the relative path is: `../images/picture`

Answer (score 9):

You need to use either absolute or relative path (maybe better in that case). If it's in the parent directory, try this code:

```
old = '..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'picture';
$new = '..' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'old.jpg';
rename($old , $new);
```

Answer (score 4):

Like Seth and Jack mentioned, the error is appearing because the script cannot find the old file. You're making it look in the current directory and not it's parent.

To fix this, either enter the full path of the old file, or try this:

```
rename("../picture.jpg", "old.jpg");
```

The `../` traverses up a single directory, in this case, the parent directory. Using `../` works in windows as well, no need to use a backslash.

If you are still getting an error after making these changes, then you may want to post your directory structure so we can all look at it.

Comment: i cant and i dont want to use fullpath. after change to thats i get error. not work for me now.` Warning: rename("../picture", "old.jpg") [function.rename]: The system cannot find the file specified. (code: 2) in C:\xampp\htdocs\prj\change.php on line 21`

Answer (score 0):

Probably you (i.e. the script at the moment where it issues the `rename()` command) are not in the directory you think you are (and/or where your files are). To debug, first display a list of the files in your directory:

```
  $d=@dir(".");// or experiment with other directories, e.g. "../files"
  while($e=$d->read()) { echo $e,"</br>"; }
```

Once you found the directory with the file in it, you can change into that directory and then do the rename without any path:

```
  chdir("../files"); // for example
  // here you can print again the dir.contents for debugging as above
  rename( "picture", "img.jpg" ); // args are: $old, $new
  // here you can print again the dir.contents for debugging as above
```

References:

- https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_directory_chdir.asp
- https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_filesystem.asp