# Using variables in rename() function PHP

Tags: php, rename

I'm trying to use variables in PHP's rename() function but I must be doing it wrong as it's not working.

```
$save = 'myfile-wf.png'; // this filename is actually created dynamically but I've just written it here for clarity. The variable is tested and working.

rename("/var/www/$save", "/var/www/html/wave/$save");
```

But it's not happening. Can you see what I'm doing wrong? Can I not use a variable in a filepath with rename()?

Comment: If you run `var_dump("/var/www/$save", "/var/www/html/wave/$save");` ([demo](https://3v4l.org/#version=5.6.22)) does it display what you need?

Comment: It will work, might be your html directory doesn't contain `wave` directory there or might be permission issue

Comment: Change the permission of www directory to 777 Recursively, this might help you.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I have no visual output at any stage, this is a backend function so I can't var_dump in it's current state. I've tried chmodding the wave dir (which 100% exists) recursively but it's still not working?

Comment: You can use a debugger, insert diagnose information in your regular output, save data into files... Feel free to ask for directions on that. What worries me know is how your determined the issue is precisely there if you have a kind of black box you can't peek into.

Comment: Oh I totally can, was just being lazy :/ This is just one script in a succession of 7 spread across 3 different webservers that all work in a chain.

Comment: Read This : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13434883/rename-file-in-php

Comment: I found the problem, the dynamic file being created by imagepng() (which I failed to mention in my original question - apologies) wasn't writeable, I've changed the permissions after creation to 755 and now it's working as expected. Thanks for all your help and comments guys.

Answer (score 2):

The [rename()](http://php.net/rename) function expects strings as parameters for paths:

> `bool rename ( string $oldname , string $newname [, resource $context ] )`

Strings don't have memory. Once you create one, PHP has no way to determine whether you created it using variables, reading data from a file or feeding it from a socket.

Most likely reasons include:

- Your strings do not contain what you think they do (as you've said, this is not actual code)
- `rename()` is throwing a warning but you haven't configured your PHP development box to display (all) errors on screen.